# Pepper QiSDk-Changing volume

Tags: android, volume, pepper

I'm working with Pepper QiSDk. I was wondering if is it possible to modulate in the code the volume of Pepper?
I tried the tag \vol=value\ but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the official API provided by Android.
[Here is a tutorial for doing so with usual Android devices](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-adjust-the-volume-of-android-phone-programmatically-from-the-app/).
It should work as well for Pepper.